# Authorization policy is breaking preflight check in APIMAN

Tags: preflight, apiman

I have 2 policies on my API (+1 for cors), first is keycloakOauthPolicy and the second is AuthorizationPolicy.

When I make some preflight request (then with verb OPTIONS and without any token in the header), I get that error from AuthorizationPolicy :

> No roles have been extracted during authentication.  Make sure the >authorization policy comes *after* a compatible authentication policy in >your configuration

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, I had a plan with another policy (keycloak authentication) which was also taking in charge or at least breaking the flow, then CORS policy (which is filtering preflight request) wasn't working properly.